# There are white parts in the variable font

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I am trying to use Source Han Sans Variable Font in LaTeX.I used the following code:

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\setCJKmainfont[
  UprightFeatures={RawFeature={+axis={wght=700}}}
]{Source Han Sans CN-VF}

\begin{document}
你好，世界！
\end{document}
```

But unluckily there are white squares in the characters:

[image: White squares in the characters]

I searched Bing and Google for similar problems but couldn't find a solution.
Can you tell me how to solve it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce.Your code compiles on my system, and looks fine. Maybe an issue with your PDF viewer?

Comment: I’ve had similar problems with Source Serif, not on screen but in print, and not on my desktop printer but in the professional print shop to which I sent a poster. Looks as if not all viewers and not all printers are ready for variable fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with my PDF viewers. Acrobat DC and Firefox both display this way, but Chrome and mobile display fine.